# Cant find Adwords tab in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, google-api

When I want to set up my adwords info under the 
System-->Configuration-->Sales-->Google API

there is no tab for Google AdWords - Conversion Tracking???

I thought that feature came preinstalled?

What I want to do in the end is to activate google shopping.

I am using Magento community 1.7.0.2

Regards,
Oliver.

Answer (score 4):

Google Adwords does not come with Magento preinstalled.

Magento has Google Analytics preinstalled.

There are several (free and paid) extensions out there. I have used the following with success: 
http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento-extension-googleanalyticsplus.html

However, I would do your own investigation and see which extension fits your coding personality and business needs.

Comment: Okay, thats what i suspected, just wasn't sure. Thank you for your quick response.